# C libcurl get output into a string

Tags: c, libcurl

I want to store the result of this curl function in a variable, how can I do so?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main(void)
{
  CURL *curl;
  CURLcode res;

  curl = curl_easy_init();
  if(curl) {
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "curl.haxx.se");
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

    /* always cleanup */
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

thanks, I solved it like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

function_pt(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *stream){
    printf("%d", atoi(ptr));
}

int main(void)
{
  CURL *curl;
  curl = curl_easy_init();
  if(curl) {
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "curl.haxx.se");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, function_pt);
    curl_easy_perform(curl);
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
  }
  system("pause");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just to point out in your solution in function_pt() you are converting the string in ptr to integer in order to convert it back to string in the output. You can output the string directly (and see the full response).

Comment: here is a link to the cURL example  http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/getinmemory.html

Comment: `CURLcode res;` is unused

Comment: same question but for C++ instead of c go to here: [Save cURL content result into a string in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9786150/52074)

Answer (score 138, accepted):

You can set a callback function to receive incoming data chunks using `curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, myfunc);`

The callback will take a user defined argument that you can set using `curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, p)`

Here's a snippet of code that passes a buffer `struct string {*ptr; len}` to the callback function and grows that buffer on each call using realloc().

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

struct string {
  char *ptr;
  size_t len;
};

void init_string(struct string *s) {
  s->len = 0;
  s->ptr = malloc(s->len+1);
  if (s->ptr == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "malloc() failed\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  s->ptr[0] = '\0';
}

size_t writefunc(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, struct string *s)
{
  size_t new_len = s->len + size*nmemb;
  s->ptr = realloc(s->ptr, new_len+1);
  if (s->ptr == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "realloc() failed\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  memcpy(s->ptr+s->len, ptr, size*nmemb);
  s->ptr[new_len] = '\0';
  s->len = new_len;

  return size*nmemb;
}

int main(void)
{
  CURL *curl;
  CURLcode res;

  curl = curl_easy_init();
  if(curl) {
    struct string s;
    init_string(&s);

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "curl.haxx.se");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, writefunc);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &s);
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

    printf("%s\n", s.ptr);
    free(s.ptr);

    /* always cleanup */
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nice. Even nicer if all those `size_t` (besides `len` itself) would be declared `const`.

Comment: for C++ `std::string` go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9786295/52074)

Answer (score 42):

The following answer is the C++ way to do it, with `std::string`, instead of null-terminated string. It still uses a callback function (there's no way around it), but also handles allocation error using try/catch.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <curl/curl.h>

size_t CurlWrite_CallbackFunc_StdString(void *contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, std::string *s)
{
    size_t newLength = size*nmemb;
    try
    {
        s->append((char*)contents, newLength);
    }
    catch(std::bad_alloc &e)
    {
        //handle memory problem
        return 0;
    }
    return newLength;
}
int main()
{
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;

    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_DEFAULT);

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    std::string s;
    if(curl)
    {

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "curl.haxx.se");

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L); //only for https
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0L); //only for https
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, CurlWrite_CallbackFunc_StdString);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &s);
        curl_easy_setopt (curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L); //remove this to disable verbose output


        /* Perform the request, res will get the return code */
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        /* Check for errors */
        if(res != CURLE_OK)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
                    curl_easy_strerror(res));
        }

        /* always cleanup */
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }

    std::cout<<s<<std::endl;

    std::cout<< "Program finished!" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I think std::string::append can make that callback function a lot simpler.

Comment: @rnickb You're right; `s->append((char*)contents. nmemb);` works flawlessly with me and is more concise. Also, the [official function signature](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION.html) for the callback has a `char*` as first argument, so you could use that and omit the casting.
And lastly, `s->resize()` actually initializes the newly allocated space. As you are about to overwrite it anyway, `s->reserve()` would be more efficient.

Comment: This helped me a lot. Can you also give an example of how to do it with HTTP POST please :-)

Answer (score 9):

From reading the manual here: http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html I think you need several calls to CURL_SETOPT, the first being the URL you want to process, the second being something like:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, function_ptr);
```

Where function_ptr matches this signature:

```
size_t function( void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *stream)
```

What happens here is you denote a callback function which libcurl will call when it has some output to write from whatever transfer you've invoked. You can get it to automatically write to a file, or pass it a pointer to a function which will handle the output itself. Using this function you should be able to assemble the various output strings into one piece and then use them in your program.

I'm not sure what other options you may have to set / what else affects how you want your app to behave, so have a good look through that page.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a C++ flavor of the accepted answer from [alex-jasmin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/162407/alex-jasmin)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <curl/curl.h>

size_t writefunc(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, std::string *s) 
{
  s->append(static_cast<char *>(ptr), size*nmemb);
  return size*nmemb;
}

int main(void)
{
  CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();
  if (curl)
  {
    std::string s;

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "curl.haxx.se");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, writefunc);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &s);

    CURLcode res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

    std::cout << s << std::endl;

    /* always cleanup */
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
  }
  return 0;
}
```