# Accessing the Twitter Streaming API with C

Tags: c, api, twitter, curl, streaming

I'm trying to access the Streaming API with C, and am using the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main(void)
{
  CURL *curl;
  CURLcode res;

  curl = curl_easy_init();
  if(curl) {
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/sample.json?delimited=length -uJEggers2:password");
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    printf("results: %c", res);
    /* always cleanup */ 
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

This prints nothing upon execution, what am I doing wrong? Thanks.
**EDIT:** The Code works when I use google.com as the URL, but it just seems to be an issue with the Streaming API. Any Ideas?

Comment: Does this work even without CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH?

Answer (score 3):

The function [curl_easy_perform()](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_perform.html) only returns the error code. To actually retrieve the data you'll have to set [CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html#CURLOPTWRITEFUNCTION) to your own callback function.

Edit: You also can't use " -uJEggers2:password" in the URL string, you'll have to set the authentication options using [CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html#CURLOPTHTTPAUTH), [CURLOPT_USERNAME](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html#CURLOPTUSERNAME) and [CURLOPT_PASSWORD](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html#CURLOPTPASSWORD).

Comment: That couldn't be right, when I use google.com instead of the Streaming API url the source code is printed. Any ideas?

Comment: Curl probably writes the output to stdout when you haven't specified your own WRITEFUNCTION. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329571/c-libcurl-get-output-into-a-string for sample code.

Comment: Also see my edit regarding user authentication, this is probably why you didn't see any output. You will still have to use a writefunction if you want to work with the output, otherwise it's just libcurl printing the output to stdout.

Comment: Could you please present here how you have solved this. I do not have an idea how should I set CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH to allow Twitter Streaming with C. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

edit:I think the difference between using google.com and the twitter API is that in this case you are trying to specify a password with " -u user:pass".  Nowhere in the CURL API do I see this technique mentioned.

Instead pass the user and pass separately with an additional curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "user:pass") as described in section "NAMES and PASSWORDS OPTIONS" at http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html

Comment: The Code works when I use google.com as the address, it prints the source code. It's just an issue with the Streaming API. Any ideas?

Comment: You said in the question that nothing is printed.  Do you mean nothing except for "results: __"?

Comment: see edit regarding user authentication, same conclusion as Flavio.

Comment: Glad it works. Please consider upvoting and choosing an answer, it'd support people answering your follow-up questions.