# Please explain this "if" in C language

Tags: c

I'm coming back to 'C' after few years. I searched the net for how to use Twitter API in C and I came across this question on stackoverflow.

Question: [Accessing the Twitter Streaming API with C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4738002/accessing-the-twitter-streaming-api-with-c)

I can't understand the "if" in this code:

```
if(curl) {
```

I can't understand it, what does it do? What is it's function? Shouldn't there be some conditional?

Please help. Thanks

Comment: `curl` is the condition. If it's not `None`, it evaluates to 'truehood'.

Comment: In C, if a variable resolves to zero, it evaluates to false.  If it is non-zero, it evaluates to true.  That if tests if the variable named "curl" evaluates to true or false.

Comment: you don't understand the `if` in C

Comment: @gipi I know    if in C but I never encountered this type of    if

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It checks to see if the pointer `curl` is not null (a null pointer is equivalent to the value `0`, which is false when considered as a Boolean).

Answer (score 0):

You should have looked at the previous three lines,

```
CURL *curl;
CURLcode res;

curl = curl_easy_init();
if(curl) {
```

In the above code, did `curl_easy_init()` succeed in initialization.

Answer (score 0):

In C language, there are no actual booleans. But 0 and 1 can be treated as booleans in C language.. where 0 is false and anything nonzero is true including negative numbers. So this curl is a pointer and is assigned zero if not initialized. Hence it checks if curl is initialized and if it is.. if block gets executed