# Twitter Stream API through C and curl

Tags: c, twitter, curl, stream

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Trying to Access Twitter Streaming API with C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8092870/trying-to-access-twitter-streaming-api-with-c)

Could anyone help me how do I code in C of getting a stream of tweets? I already have read how to output results through [C libcurl get output into a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329571/c-libcurl-get-output-into-a-string).
I also know how to get a stream of tweets just through 'curl' in the command terminal.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you're asking for the basic pattern of a CURL request, which I personally thought was not that well written in the tutorial.  It seemed like a dozen lines of code should provide the basic pattern for how to use CURL, but I didn't see it written like that in a tutorial.  Hope this helps:

```
CURL *handle;
char PostFields[512];

/* initialise curl */
curl_global_init( CURL_GLOBAL_ALL )
handle = curl_easy_init();

/* set options to post */
curl_easy_setopt( handle, CURLOPT_URL, TwitterUrl );
curl_easy_setopt( handle, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );

sprintf( PostFields, "user_id=%s?screen_name=%s", TwitterId, TwitterName );
curl_easy_setopt( handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, (void*)PostFields );
curl_easy_setopt( handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSSIZE, strlen( PostFields ) );

/* set options to handle response */
curl_easy_setopt( handle, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, HandleTwitterHeader );
curl_easy_setopt( handle, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, HandleTwitterResponse );

/* do the request */
curl_easy_perform( handle );
curl_easy_cleanup( handle );
```

Comment: Will this output a stream of tweets? Or just a single tweet?

Comment: Neither, it is just example CURL code to post a request - you say you know how to get a stream at the command line, while I am not familiar with the Twitter API.  You should be able to use your CURL command line before the ? as the TwitterUrl, and the bit after as your PostFields data.

Comment: NB: it sounded like you were originally asking for pointers in writing this code for yourself.  If you are looking for it already written, look here: http://code.google.com/p/twitcurl/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand your question, and I am not sure you are understanding it well.

Perhaps your issue is related to JSON in C. There are several C (& C++) libraries for JSON. You could use [jansson](http://www.digip.org/jansson/)

Comment: I am sorry for the confusing question. Actually I don't care about outputting the results to a JSON file. What I wanted to actually do is getting a Twitter stream using the curl.h library in C. I edited my question. Thanks.

Comment: According to https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/post/direct_messages/new you should care about JSON. You don't need to put JSON in a file (you could produce JSON into a string and transmit it).

Comment: Yes. I know that. Twitter API returns tweets in JSON format. Moreover, I know how to parse a JSON file. What matters most for me is how can I consume the Twitter Stream by coding in C.

Comment: Use curl for the HTTP part, and Jansson for the Json part.

Comment: Yes. Exactly. But any sample codes?

Comment: Both curl and Jansson documentation have tutorials with examples. That should be enough. Of course, you need to understand the twitter API.