# Reading a file downloaded via libcurl

Tags: c++, curl, libcurl

How can I download a file using libcurl and rather than save it to disk, just read its file contents? I see that I can use the WRITEFUNCTION to write the file to disk, but I do not see how I can just pull from the server and read without saving to disk first.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Save cURL content result into a string in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9786150/save-curl-content-result-into-a-string-in-c)

Comment: it is not a duplicate, I have mote than just a strung to read and don't wish to read everything into a string and parse it

Comment: `std::string` was used in that case to store the content of the file that was downloaded. And even if you don't want to use  `std::string` for the job, that code shows exactly what needs to be done, and how to do it. **It is a duplicate**.

Comment: You need to understand that a data file is nothing but a sequence of bytes. The code from the possible duplicate shows how to use CURL and retrieve a remote file, and store the entire file in the memory, using `std::string` for that. Whatever you need to do with this file after that, is outside the scope of the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use WRITEFUNCTION to write anywhere you want, even keeping things in memory only without writing to disk. Look at the example in the `libcurl` website:

http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/getinmemory.html

The example is C-ish, but you can easily replace the allocations with a `vector<byte>` or a `string`

Comment: oh ok, and the MemoryChunck is ny data in the file? what if everything is not just a struct but more complex

Comment: You can pass anything you want as the user data pointer and then cast and use it however you want. You could pass a string, as in the question @karlphillip posted above or you could pass your own more complex data structure