# Get the http response for a URL in C++

Tags: c++, url, httpresponse, http-response-codes

I want to simply get the HTTP response or simple pass/fail for a URL in C++

Something like the AJAX call I use in JavaScript

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://www.google.com",
    dataType: "html",
    timeout: 4 * 1000
}).done(function() {

})
.fail(function() {

});
```

Half the solutions I've seem far too convoluted. In search of a simpler way.

Comment: What do you find so difficult about [`getaddrinfo`](http://manpages.courier-mta.org/htmlman3/getaddrinfo.3.html)() followed by [`socket`](http://manpages.courier-mta.org/htmlman2/socket.2.html)(), then [`connect`](http://manpages.courier-mta.org/htmlman2/connect.2.html)(), then [`write`](http://manpages.courier-mta.org/htmlman2/write.2.html)(), and finally [`read`](http://manpages.courier-mta.org/htmlman2/read.2.html)()?

Comment: I agree @SamVarshavchik more methods = less errors, and more specific

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I clearly didn't find an example whilst scouring the web that put forth that solution. I will look into it

Comment: HTTP is not trivial to implement by hand (look at all the questions on StackOverflow of people having trouble writing their own HTTP clients).  I would not recommend the `connect()`/`write()`/`read()` approach unless you are really good at socket programming and are prepared to implement all of the nuances that HTTP requires to *properly* handle the server's response.

Comment: cURL is your friend. Here is a similar question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9786150/save-curl-content-result-into-a-string-in-c

Comment: For one-off fetch of a known document, of a known MIME content-type, from a fixed URL, a plain socket connection will work just fine. The nice thing about HTTP is how gracefully it degrades to the lowest common denominator between the client and the server. The server is not going to send a pipelined response, nor a byte range response, nor a compress response, unless the client indicates its support for it.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at the [CPR](https://github.com/whoshuu/cpr) library:

```
auto response = cpr::Get // or cpr::Head
(
    cpr::Url{"http://www.google.com"},
    cpr::Header{{"accept", "text/html"}},
    cpr::Timeout{4 * 1000}
);

if(response.status_code != 200)
{
    // fail
}
```

Comment: This certainly looks like the simple solution I was looking for. Is CPR the only library I have to import into my project?

Comment: @DanJamesPalmer `CPR` is a "wrapper" library for [CURL](https://curl.haxx.se/) so you also need to install [CURL](https://curl.haxx.se/).

Comment: For quickly getting up and running, cpr does include cURL inside of the repository as a submodule. There should be instructions in the [Usage](https://github.com/whoshuu/cpr#usage) section that will help you get started. Additionally, you can clone or fork the [example repository](https://github.com/whoshuu/cpr-example) with all the necessary CMake scaffolding you need to make a simple GET request.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [libcurl](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/), eg:

```
#include <curl/curl.h> 

CURL *c = curl_easy_init(); 
if (!c)
{
    ...
}
else
{
    struct curl_slist *headers = curl_slist_append(NULL, "Accept: text/html");

    curl_easy_setopt(c, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.google.com");
    curl_easy_setopt(c, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers); 
    curl_easy_setopt(c, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 4 * 1000);
    curl_easy_setopt(c, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);

    CURLcode res = curl_easy_perform(c);
    curl_slist_free_all(headers);

    if (res != CURLE_OK)
    {
        ...
    }
    else
    {
        long responseCode;
        curl_easy_getinfo(c, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE, &responseCode); 

        ...
    }

    curl_easy_cleanup(c);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In some cases I used [HappyHTTP](http://scumways.com/happyhttp/happyhttp.html), since it's small and easy to use. It is somewhat limited, but depending on what you need it can get the job done.

I changed their example program a bit to give you an idea of how to use it for your purpose:

```
// invoked when response headers have been received
void OnBegin( const happyhttp::Response* r, void* userdata )
{
     *userdata = r->getstatus();
}

// invoked to process response body data (may be called multiple times)
void OnData( const happyhttp::Response* r, void* userdata, const unsigned char* data, int n )
{

}

// invoked when response is complete
void OnComplete( const happyhttp::Response* r, void* userdata )
{

}


void TestGET()
{
    int returnStatus;
    happyhttp::Connection conn( "www.google.com", 80 );
    conn.setcallbacks( OnBegin, OnData, OnComplete, &returnStatus );

    conn.request( "GET", "/" );

    while( conn.outstanding() ) conn.pump();

    if (returnStatus != 200) printf("FAIL");
    else printf("OK");
}
```

In order to make it work on VS2015, you can use the following lazy solution: add the following to the start of happyhttp.cpp.

```
#ifdef WIN32
    #pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")
    #define strcasecmp _stricmp
    #define _WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS
    #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#endif
```

Comment: Hi Alain-Jacques, I am trying to implement your suggestion. I've downloaded the .h and .cpp files for HappyHTTP and added them to my project. I've included them in the .cc file I want to use. I get the following errors when trying to compile in VS2015. Any ideas? https://postimg.org/image/jz0xu87d1/

Comment: @DanJamesPalmer, I edited the answer with a lazy solution for your VS2015 trouble. The thing is, the compiler is mostly complaining about usage of unsafe string calls and deprecated socket functions. There are better ways to solve this, such as replacing sprintf for snprintf for instance, which states the length of the buffer avoiding possible memory problems.

Comment: Thanks Alain-Jacques, that did indeed get rid of the errors. I now have a new issue. See https://postimg.org/image/434d3es11/. I'm taking over this project from someone else. It appears all the methods have to be part of the CSpeedTest umbrella. When I put the happyHTTP methods under that umbrella I get the error. Removing the CSpeedTest solve the error but I then can't call CheckACM from other methods....

Comment: Since you're talking about non-static methods, you will get the argument incompatibility error. Maybe you can define the callbacks as friend functions, so they can access internal members of CSpeedTest, and place them outside the class.