# Nameless class or object or function, the meaning of code

Tags: c++, xcode, curl, unreal-engine4

I can't understand the meaning of function

```
size_t WriteCallback(char *contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp)
{
    ((std::string*)userp)->append((char*)contents, size * nmemb);
    return size * nmemb;
}
```

I was trying to run simple curl function on c++, for usage inside ue4.
Curl works fine, but i am trying to read response, receive response into string, as it works kinda js ajax.

Found the solution [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9786150/save-curl-content-result-into-a-string-in-c)

In xcode c++ works fine

But in ue4 :

using std::string

```
    ((std::string*)userp)->append((char*)contents, size * nmemb);
/Users/Documents/Unreal Projects/curlTest/Source/curlTest/curlTestCharacter.cpp:114:7: error: no member named 'string' in namespace 'std'; did you mean 'cString'?
```

Using cString :

```
    ((cString*)userp)->append((char*)contents, size * nmemb);
/Users/Documents/Unreal Projects/curlTest/Source/curlTest/curlTestCharacter.cpp:114:15: error: expected expression
```

Trying to find out the reason, but don't know the function above, how it works, if xcode runs fine so then, for what reason is it so. Anonymous function , pointer and some features of c++?

How can i use this code more human, or more easily, and how to deal with errors?

No math, no addition - subtraction, var or func, class or object, what is the meaning if this code

```
((std::string*)userp)->append((char*)contents, size * nmemb);
```

And as i still didn't found how to receive curl response as easy as ajax does, this still may work, but how does it works and how can i use it?

Any help, two days trying to figure out, trying to simply run the curl which i previously used so easy in command line and php code

Comment: I don't think `cString` has an `append` method.  You will need look at the docs and find the equivalent method.

Comment: From the error message I would guess that `cString` doesn't have an `append` method.

Comment: You need to cast `userp` back to the type of object it actually points to. `(char*)contents` is super unnecessary.

Comment: @RichardCritten i was trying to use std::string but still having error "error: no member named 'string' in namespace 'std'; did you mean 'cString'" . Is there in curl option just to receive response as a content

Comment: I think you're missing a `#include <string>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
size_t WriteCallback(char *contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp)
{
    ((std::string*)userp)->append((char*)contents, size * nmemb);
    return size * nmemb;
}
```

Without any further context, I would guess that this is some callback a library (curl maybe?) is calling to let you process received data. `contents` is the string data itself, `size` and `nmemb` describe how much data is in the string (`size` is the width of each character and `nmemb` is the count of characters, perhaps?), `userp` is a custom data pointer you probably pass in when you call the function that generates calls to this callback. I'm guessing that you're meant to return the number of bytes you processed.

In the case of this particular function, I'm guessing you're passing in a `std::string` pointer. Whenever this library has received data, it's appending it into your `std::string`.

```
((std::string*)userp)->append((char*)contents, size * nmemb);
/Users/Documents/Unreal Projects/curlTest/Source/curlTest/curlTestCharacter.cpp:114:7: error: no member named 'string' in namespace 'std'; did you mean 'cString'?
```

This is caused by not including the header - add `#include <string>` at the top of your source file.

```
((cString*)userp)->append((char*)contents, size * nmemb);
/Users/Documents/Unreal Projects/curlTest/Source/curlTest/curlTestCharacter.cpp:114:15: error: expected expression
```

It would appear that the `cString` class does not have a member function called `append`. You'll have to either look at the `cString`'s header file or consult its documentation to work out what the appropriate function to use is.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i really didn't used header "string" because i thought that string is every where is string, std::string is kinda object which has methods, it is the same as assignment. Thanks for the answer. I am new for c++ and it really helped to figure out