# My libcurl based program doesn't work from the point of the first "curl_easy_setopt" and returns 0xC0000374

Tags: c++, libcurl

I downloaded files from libcurl, moved certain files to their folders in MINGW, added curl in linker settings (I have codeblocks) and wrote this program. Somehow, it stops and returns code -1073740940 (0xC0000374) at the very line
`res = curl_easy_setopt(curl1, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str());`
The whole part of the code which I was testing looks like that:

```
string html_to_string (string url)
{
    string s;
    cout << "chp" << endl;
    CURL *curl1;
    cout << "chp" << endl;
    CURLcode res;
    cout << "chp" << endl;
    res = curl_easy_setopt(curl1, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str());
    cout << "chp" << endl;
    if(res != CURLE_OK)
    {
        cout << "blad1" << endl;
    }
    cout << "chp" << endl;
    res = curl_easy_setopt(curl1, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &s);
    if(res != CURLE_OK)
    {
        cout << "blad2" << endl;
    }
    cout << "chp" << endl;
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl1);
    if(res != CURLE_OK)
    {
        cout << "blad3" << endl;
    }
    cout << "chp"<< endl;
    return s;
}

int main()
{
    string url = "https://om.mimuw.edu.pl/";
    string htmlcode = html_to_string (url);
    cout << htmlcode;
}
```

The function is meant to get the html response and put it inside a string for further changes. Right now I want to focus on the first part and get html code to string.

Comment: I believe you need to do `CURL *curl1 = curl_easy_init();` instead of `CURL *curl1;`

Comment: Where do you initialize `curl1`?  I assume that has to be done before calling any curl functions.

Comment: `res = curl_easy_setopt(curl1, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str());` -- You can't accomplish anything by passing an uninitialized pointer, `curl1`.  In general, a C++ function that takes a `char *` requires that the `char *` point somewhere valid, or is a `nullptr` -- no other circumstance does it makes sense (or even work).  The function cannot change that pointer within the function, since the pointer is passed by value.

Comment: You're going to want to set `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION` if you want to append the data to the string you set for `CURLOPT_WRITEDATA`.

Comment: Several examples here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9786150/save-curl-content-result-into-a-string-in-c

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie everything you said is true, but what you said about the `char*` pointer is completely irrelevant to this issue. `curl1` is uninitialized - period. The use of `url.c_str()` is perfectly fine in this code.

Comment: Side note: google the error code. Often it will give you more information you can use to narrow the problem down.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. Yup. I didn't init the *curl. Sorry for that sloppiness. I am sort of a rookie especially with non-standard libraries. It works now, but there is another problem with performing this curl, but it's for another question or my own solution.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the comments. Yup. The solution was getting   `CURL *curl1 = curl_easy_init();` line instead of just  `CURL *curl1;`