# In C, how do you use libcurl to read a HTTP response into a string?

Tags: c, string, libcurl, httpresponse

I have homework where I need somehow to compare two HTTP responses. I am writing it on C  and I use libcurl to make things easier. I am calling the function that uses libcurl to do a HTTP request and response from another function, and I want to return the HTTP response as a `char *`. Here is my code so far (it crashes):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <string.h>

size_t write_data(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *stream) {
    size_t written;
    written = fwrite(ptr, size, nmemb, stream);
    return written;
}

char *handle_url(void) {
    CURL *curl;
    char *fp;
    CURLcode res;
    char *url = "http://www.yahoo.com";
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, fp);
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        if(res != CURLE_OK)
                fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",   curl_easy_strerror(res));

        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);

        //printf("\n%s", fp);
    }
    return fp;
}
```

This solution [C libcurl get output into a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329571/c-libcurl-get-output-into-a-string?rq=1) works, but not in my case because I just want to return the string to the calling function.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is `char *fp;`? Why are you returning it? How/where are you allocating memory for it? Where are my glasses?

Comment: lol. i had years to write C so i am back to zero. The thing is that it's working in the "C libcurl get output into a string" example i am refering above. I don't know the exact data input so i am not sure if allocating memory for char *fp will work.

Comment: Your `write_data` should be passed `char *fp` as a parameter, but you've defined it to take a `FILE`. Also, you'll likely need to handle the case where your `write_func` gets called more than once. Finally, if you want this to work as you expect, `char *fp` is going to have to be passed into `write_func()` as a pointer to a pointer, so you can properly allocate it. In other words, your `write_func()` should take a `char**`, not a `FILE*`.

Comment: i know that this code is a mess. thanks for the help guys. changing FILE to char** returns this error: main.c:7: warning: passing arg 4 of `fwrite' from incompatible pointer type

Comment: licurl's example uses void *stream. which also is not working.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Fixed it for you. You need to handle the case where the `write_data()` function is called multiple times, and pass it the right kind of parameter. You also need to keep track of how big a structure you've got, so you can allocate enough memory.

I left in a debug `printf` in the `write_data` function to help you understand how it works.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct url_data {
    size_t size;
    char* data;
};

size_t write_data(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, struct url_data *data) {
    size_t index = data->size;
    size_t n = (size * nmemb);
    char* tmp;

    data->size += (size * nmemb);

#ifdef DEBUG
    fprintf(stderr, "data at %p size=%ld nmemb=%ld\n", ptr, size, nmemb);
#endif
    tmp = realloc(data->data, data->size + 1); /* +1 for '\0' */

    if(tmp) {
        data->data = tmp;
    } else {
        if(data->data) {
            free(data->data);
        }
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate memory.\n");
        return 0;
    }

    memcpy((data->data + index), ptr, n);
    data->data[data->size] = '\0';

    return size * nmemb;
}

char *handle_url(char* url) {
    CURL *curl;

    struct url_data data;
    data.size = 0;
    data.data = malloc(4096); /* reasonable size initial buffer */
    if(NULL == data.data) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate memory.\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    data.data[0] = '\0';

    CURLcode res;

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &data);
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        if(res != CURLE_OK) {
                fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",  
                        curl_easy_strerror(res));
        }

        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);

    }
    return data.data;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    char* data;

    if(argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Must provide URL to fetch.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    data = handle_url(argv[1]);

    if(data) {
        printf("%s\n", data);
        free(data);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Note: compile with `gcc -o test test.c -lcurl` (assuming you pasted into `test.c`). Use `gcc -o test test.c -lcurl -DDEBUG` to see the test `printf()` calls.

Disclaimer: this is ugly, quick-and-dirty code. There may be bugs. Please see the [more robust, better commented example here](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/getinmemory.html).

Comment: thank you @Mike, it works!!! now i only need to remember(read) how alloc and malloc works.

Comment: congratulations, you re-implemented the getinmemory.c libcurl example: http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/getinmemory.html :-)

Comment: @Daniel, hah, thanks for the link. It was a fun exercise to figure out anyway. =)

Comment: @Daniel, I noticed one small bug in your example. The line that says `mem->memory = realloc(mem->memory, ...)` isn't quite correct. The manual page (at least, on OS X) indicates that `For realloc(), the input pointer is still valid if reallocation failed.` So this could be a leak. (I made the same mistake with my fist quick-and-dirty version. I usually avoid using `realloc()` so wanted to double-check.) I noticed the lack of `'\0'` termination for the string during `write_data()` as well, which I also fixed, but strangely that wasn't ever causing a problem.

Comment: Don't forget to call curl_global_cleanup();, otherwise you'll have leaks.