# libcurl getting exception with writedata/ and WRITEFUNCTION

Tags: visual-c++, libcurl

I'm trying to capture the data that is returned from the web site into a char array (instead of letting libcurl write it to stdout), so I can process it. I get an illegal wright exception.

"Unhandled exception at 0x775E8E19 (ntdll.dll) in trailing_stop_loss.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00EBDC90."

I'm using MS Visual Studio Express 2012.

Any help welcome. Thank you,

Here is the code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string> 
#include "curl.h"

using namespace std;

int main(void) {
  CURL *curl;
  CURLcode res;

  curl = curl_easy_init();
  if(curl) {

    char *webData[1000];
int i;
for (i=0; i<1000; i++) {webData[i] = "z";}

curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://finance.yahoo.com /d/quotes.csv?s=GOOG&f=sd1p");
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, NULL);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, (void *)webData);
res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
if(res != CURLE_OK)`enter code here`
       fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n", curl_easy_strerror(res));
else {`enter code here`
  cout << webData;
}

/* always cleanup */
curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
}
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [C libcurl get output into a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329571/c-libcurl-get-output-into-a-string)

Answer (score 0):

Setting CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION to NULL will make libcurl use fwrite() and the CURLOPT_WRITEDATA must then be the FILE * to write data to.

If you want to receive data directly into memory, you must also write your own write callback. There's an example on the libcurl site showing exactly this:

http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/getinmemory.html

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I will follow your advise.