# Compare HTML from libcurl with text from file

Tags: c, utf-8, ascii, libcurl, libiconv

I'm using libcurl to connect to a website, and getting the HTML, I'm also using LibTidy to extract the text. My purpose is to verify if a sentence from a text file is inside the HTML.

Thanks to LibTidy I have all the text file as one char*.
I'm using : char *strstr(const char *one, const char *two) for comparing the two strings.
The first one is the string from libcurl and libTidy parsing, and the second one is a string from a text file.

When I'm using the function strstr(..) I have NULL as result.
Using the debugger show my that the two string aren't 'encode' in the same way.

[image]

I tried to found where the problem was for the String resulting of the Internet connection. And I tried different sample of code to tried to fix it.

The code given by the libcurl website, give me the same problem, the char *memory isn't encoded well, and I can't compare it properly.
https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/getinmemory.html

I also tried the code here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/2329792/10160890, and the char *ptr have the same problem.

I expect to be able to compare the String from libcurl and the String from text file.

Comment: Have you tried dumping the text you get back as hex so you can see the values of the characters? Are you sure that `strlen(in_str)` is returning the right value? Seems like a good task for a debugger so you examine what's going on.

Comment: Yes the debugguer help me a lot, I think the problem came from the function with tidy parsing.

Comment: You should revert the edit. The new text is not an answerable question.

Comment: What is the character encoding of the text file? (It appears not to be compatible with ASCII so why have you referenced ASCII?)

Comment: Note: Despite debuggers being incredibly powerful, you should not expect one to know the character encoding of data in `char` data types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to convert. Any ASCII text **is** UTF-8 text, so you just search for it as-is using `strstr`. This is pretty much the whole point of UTF-8.

Comment: The text from the file is encoded properly (See on the debugguer) but the String from the tidy parsing isn't right, that's why the function "strstr" return NULL value, but I would like to found a way to encode both in the same way to compare them.

Comment: It looks to me like your debugger is just configured to think strings are latin1 or windows1252 or some other backwards encoding rather than UTF-8.

Comment: There is no only the debugger, because the function strstr return NULL, I guess libcurl don't return the value in UTF-8. I tried the following code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329571/c-libcurl-get-output-into-a-string and the result is the same, in the debugger, the String isn't encoded well.

Comment: I think you're misdiagnosing your problem.